# JDK compliance - a false safety?

Tags: java, compilation, cross-compiling, backwards-compatibility

I have Java 7 installed but set my projects JDK compliance to Java 6. Unfortunately it turned out that this is not the same as compiling with Java 6.

For example, the interface `javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream`
extends `Closable` in Java 7 which is not the case in Java 6. Using an `ImageInputStream` where a `Closable` is expected compiles fine under my settings (Java 7 complying to Java 6) but gives an compile error when using Java 6.
Is this supposed to be this way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to compile Java code for an older JRE, you need to do two things:

- Set the compliance level appropriately. This, as explained by dystroy, makes sure the compiler produces bytecode that the old JVM can understand.
- Use the old Java system libraries. This makes sure you compile against the version of the Java system libraries (java.lang.* , java.net.* etc.) that shipped with the old JRE.

You have covered the first point, but not the second, hence your problem.

How to do this depends on your build environment.

- In Eclipse, the Java system library to use is set as part of the build path: Go to Project properties / Java Build Path / Libraries, then remove the wrong "JRE System Library" and add the right one using "Add Library...".
- When compiling with plain `javac`, you use option `-bootclasspath`. Example: `javac -target 1.5 -bootclasspath jdk1.5.0/lib/rt.jar OldCode.java` (from the [javac manpage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html), section "Cross-Compilation Options").

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was hoping newer Java versions would somehow know about the library class api differences to the older versions.

Answer (score 6):

What you have set with the JDK compliance is mostly the class format.

There were several evolutions in the bytecode format of classes. A JDK can compile in a previous format while a VM can't execute a class compiled on a more recent format.

But the used libraries always are the one available in the JDK you use for execution. The JDK 6 version of javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream isn't bundled with Java 7.

Comment: You say "there is little guarantee given by Oracle regarding the stability of the API of the javax packages", but that is absolutely not true. `javax.*` packages are standard packages, and the ones that come with the JDK are as much part of the standard library as the `java.*` packages. Perhaps you were thinking of `sun.*` packages, which of course are non-standard.

Comment: @TomAnderson Yes, you're true. I don't have time just now to look for references but it seems to me that historically they're more changing than the java one.

Comment: Yes, i think that's true. It's often the case that new APIs are added as `javax.*` packages, which inevitably means they're changing. Still, once one is in the JDK, it's staying. Changes will be backwards-compatible.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `bootclasspath` option when compiling.  I thought the JDK 7 warned of not doing so, if doing [cross-compilation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-options).

Comment: Actually, I believe the official way is to use `-bootclasspath` (`-Xbootclasspath` is a non-standard option).